# Error using thread module: This Perl not built to support threads?

Tags: perl, perl-module

In script, I'm using threads and Thread::Queue and also using version perl 5.18.2. when I run my scripts it gives Error:**This Perl not built to support threads**
In documentation, I read, it is an error. 
What is the possible solution to resolve this?

Comment: Compile yourself a new perl that can handle threads? If you're using `perlbrew` to compile your perls, then threading is an option that is not activated by default – you can use the `--thread` flag.

Comment: No I'm not using perlbrew. I'm using Thread::Queue(which has dependency with threads). I have installed perl in seperate directory(not inside root directory).

Comment: [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) is a script that makes it easy to compile your own perl with any features you whish. You cannot `use threads` on a perl that wasn't compiled with threading support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build Perl, you need to use `-Dusethreads` to make a build of Perl that supports threads.

```
sh ./Configure -Dusethreads
make test
make install
```

I personally use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install Perl.

```
perlbrew install 5.18.2 --as=5.18.2t -Dusethreads
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`forks` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/forks) is a drop-in replacement for `threads`. It supports the same API, so the only change needed is to replace

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
```

by

```
use forks;
use forks::shared;
```

You then use the same threading API, i.e. `threads->create(\&worker)` or something like that. The modules `forks` and `forks::shared` should be the first module you load. Note that `forks` has different performance characteristics from `threads`: Forking off a new process is cheaper than starting a thread (with the `threads` module), but communication between processes is more expensive than communication between threads.

Because `forks` is a *drop-in replacement* for `threads`, it works *just fine* with a `Thread::Queue`:

```
use forks;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new;

my @workers = map { threads->create(\&worker, $q) } 1..3;

$q->enqueue(1..9);
$q->end;

$_->join for @workers;

sub worker {
    my $q = shift;
    my $tid = threads->tid;
    while(defined(my $item = $q->dequeue)) {
        say "$tid got $item";
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
1 got 1
2 got 2
3 got 3
1 got 4
2 got 5
3 got 6
1 got 7
2 got 8
3 got 9
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to change `use threads::shared;`. `use forks;` causes subsequent `use threads;` and `use threads::shared;` to be equivalent to `use forks;` and `use forks::shared;`.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your source code you can load the *forks* module first, which will allow a program to use the *threads* API.

```
perl -Mforks -e 'use threads'
```

*or*

```
perl -Mforks myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to happen if you current version was not enable with a IN-BUILT thread.

I'm using plenv to install perl, and using carton as a package manager and I have tried to run `plenv install [perl-version] -Dusethreads --as [perl-version]-threads` to enable, but failed.

Thus, I had to use forks instead of using threads.

```
use forks;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $total_thread_number = 10;
my @workers;
my @final_responses;

my @workers = map { 
   threads->create(\&send_transaction) 
} 1..$total_thread_number;

foreach my $worker (@workers) {
    my $response = $worker->join;
    push @final_responses, $response;
}

sub send_transaction {
    my ($transaction) = shift;
    # do your things
}

# read final responses
foreach my $response (@final_responses){
   say ( dumper($response));            
}
```

instead of using

```
   use threads; # this seems to work with perl enabled with in-built thread
   for ((1 .. $total_thread_number)) {
        push @workers, async {
            send_transaction($transaction);
        };
    }
```

Create a working git project with sample code.
https://github.com/Aibier/loadtesting